# How to make an average in a row and then save it using afterSave() in Yii

Tags: php, yii

1. In a table I've 3 columns nota1, nota2, nota3 of table Notas.
2. I want to calc the average of nota1, nota2, nota3
3. Then I want to save using beforeSave() method the average result on nota_final field

**This is my code in the model Notas.php:**

```
    public function getAvg()
     {
        $avg = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('(nota1 + nota2 + nota3)/3 as NotaFinal')
        ->from('notas')   
        ->queryRow();
        return $avg;

    }

    protected function afterSave()

    {
        if($this->isNewRecord){

        $this->nota_final->Avg();
        $this->isNewRecord= false;
        $this->nota_final->saveAttributes($_POST['nota_final']);
        if($model->save() == false) var_dump($model->errors);
        }
    return parent::afterSave(); 

    }
```

It's not saving the avg value and it's not display any error.

What's wrong?

**my View/notas/_form.php**

```
 tr>
                    <td><div class="row2">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'nota1'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'nota1', array('maxlength'=>'3')); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'nota1'); ?>
                </div></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="row2">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'nota2'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'nota2', array('maxlength'=>'3', 'input'=>'20px')); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'nota2'); ?>
                </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                <div class="row2">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'nota3'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'nota3', array('maxlength'=>'3')); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'nota3'); ?>
                </div>
                <td>
                <div class="row2">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'nota_final'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'nota_final', array('readOnly'=>true)); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'nota_final'); ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: Where do you call save() or afterSave() method?

Comment: Your select is calculating and selecting for all rows. You need to limit it with a where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function getAvg() // remove this method
{

}

protected function beforeSave() // change to beforeSave()
{
    if($this->isNewRecord) {
        // Copy attributes from $_POST
        $this->nota_final->saveAttributes($_POST['nota_final']);

        // Calculate average
        $this->nota_final->avg = 
           ($this->nota_final->nota1 + $this->nota_final->nota2 + 
            $this->nota_final->nota3) / 3;

        // DO NOT NEED TO CALL ->save() here, it will result in loop. 
        // Do it in your controller, and this beforeSave method will be triggered
    }
    return parent::beforeSave(); // change to beforeSave
}
```

Comment: This is better solution and it's working: protected function beforeSave() 
  {
      $this->nota_final = 
             ($this->nota1 + $this->nota2 + $this->nota3 + $this->nota4) / 4;
      
      return parent::beforeSave();
  }

Comment: @YovanyA If you have a different solution, please post it as a new answer rather posting it in comments or trying to edit someone else's answer.